# Is there a way to automatically fill cells in a row when it is added in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I don't really know much about excel especially VBA. But i need to write something(macro for ex.) that does the following:

if someone inserts a row and fills the first 4 cells of it, it needs to sort the rows (i have a macro for sorting called "sortingmacro") and then it needs to fill cells 7 and 8 by copying the cells above them.

for example if i insert a row to 4th line and fill A4,B4,C4 and D4 it needs to copy G3 to G4 and H3 to H4. (after sorting of course)

any help is appreciated.

**edit:**
i have formulas in the cells that are to be copied. the formulas for the first row(the top one according to sorting) is a different one and all the others are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So put a button on the page, then go to the code for it (the click event).  In that, use your sortingmacro to sort all the rows.  Then you just do something simple like:

```
Rows(4).Cells(1,7).Formula = Rows(3).Cells(1,7).Formula
Rows(4).Cells(1,8).Formula = Rows(3).Cells(1,8).Formula
```

Of course instead of hardcoding 4 in there, you'd have a variable for the row (make sure and determine it after sorting).

Comment: thanks. but can it be done automatically when a row is inserted? i know it IS a silly question but my boss wants it

Comment: @bliss, How are you inserting it?  You can use the Worksheet_Change event like cularis suggested, and test against the inserted cells (depending on how you insert).

Comment: and why do i need to write Rows(4).Cells(1,7) why not Rows(4).Cells(7)  ?

Comment: @bliss, that will work also, I just didn't tighten things up.  Also you might use a different range than Rows() in which case Cells() might need both indices.

Comment: thanks again. and if i need the formula to be hardcoded how can i write it? i tried Rows(a).Cells(1,7)= "WORKDAY(INDIRECT(ADRESS(2;MATCH("Başlangıç Tarihi";A1:M1;0)));(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(); MATCH("Süre"; A1:M1;0))))/K2)"

and it didn't work. I tried
Rows(a).Cells(1,7)=WorksheetFunction.Workday(INDIRECT(ADRESS(2;MATCH("Başlangıç Tarihi";A1:M1;0)));(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(); MATCH("Süre"; A1:M1;0))))/K2)
and it didn't work either. I tried to write WorksheetFunction and Application in front of every formula i used and neither one worked :(

Comment: Well first off you need the `.Formula` on the left-hand side, then the right-hand side just needs to end up as a string with an `=` in front of it.

Comment: so i think you mean Rows(a).Cells(1, 7).Formula = "=WORKDAY(INDIRECT(ADRESS( (ROW() -1); COLUMN())); (INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(); MATCH("Süre"; A1:M1;0))))/K2)"

but that didn't work either :$

Comment: You need to be more specific about what `didn't work` means.  did you get an error message, the wrong value, or no formula in the cell at all?  Also you misspelled ADDRESS (the first one) and you may have an extra parentheses in there, but it's hard to be sure what you're doing.

Comment: Try it with a simple formula first to make sure you're getting the syntax right.

Comment: it says compile error expected: end of statement and it marks the word "süre"

Comment: Oh, you need single quotes on the Sure, since otherwise you're ending the string.

Answer (score 3):

You can find out if a cell has been changed with the `Worksheet_Change`-Event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print Target.Address
End Sub
```

Output (something like this):

```
$A$14
$B$17
$C$13
$C$21
$C$16
```

So if a matching cell is changed, look for the other 3 in the row and start your macro.